# Algorithm used by a CAD software to copy drawings

Tags: vector-spaces, algorithms

On CAD software it is possible to copy a drawing $A$ with points, lines, ... (with UCS A) to a drawing $B$ (with UCS B) specifying a origin point on drawing $A$ and a destination point on drawing $B$.

For example on drawing $A$ there are points $A_1 (A_{1x}, A_{1y}, A_{1z})$ and point $A_2 (A_{2x}, A_{2y}, A_{2z})$ besides there is a UCSA (CAD define this with A origin $OA_x, OA_y, OA_z$ and $2$ unit vectors for $X$-axis and $Y$-axis directions: [Link](https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/ucs_dxf_04.htm).

On drawing $B$ there are points $B_1 (B_{1x}, B_{1y}, B_{1z})$ and a UCSB (CAD define as UCSA).

On CAD I can copy $A_2$ from drawing $A$ to drawing $B$ using $A_1$ as origin and $B_1$ as destination. CAD software will use the UCSA and UCSB to transform the point before copy.

My question is: which algorithm the CAD software use to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Autodesk.

Comment: Can you explain the terms like UCS? Assume no knowledge of CAD and your CAD program. If we are able to understand the geometric / computational problem, we might have a suggestion.

Comment: @mvw a UCS is a User Cartesian System, UCSA and UCSB are 2 different cartesian coordinate system define respect a WCS (World Cartesian System) between a origin and 2 unit version for X and Y axis

Comment: OK, I think it works roughly as I sketched out below, with transformations from world coordinates to the local coordinate systems UCSA and UCSB, and back. Not sure if your $A_2$ is in coordinates regarding UCSA, but that would make sense to me, and why you first mention origin $OA$ and then origin $OA_1$. Maybe you can have a look at that answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

So the first user coordinate system UCSA has origin $a=OA$, and two unit vectors, all in world coordinates.

I assume these are orthogonal unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$, so the missing $u_3$ is simply the vector product $u_1 \times u_2$.

The transformation $T_{WA}$ from world coordinates to UCSA coordinates then has the properties:
$$
T_{WA}(a) = 0 \\
T_{WA}(u_i) = e_i \\
$$
Thus the world coordinates origin vector $a$ turns into the local coordinates vector $0$ and the unit vectors (in world coordinates) turn into the canonical unit vectors, so for [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
z' \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & -a \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with
$$
A = (u_1-a, u_2-a, u_3-a)
$$
The transformation $T_{WB}$ from world coordinates to UCSB would be constructed in a similar fashion.

Coordinates from UCSA to UCSB then might be transformed via:
$$
T_{AB} = T_{WB} \, T_{WA}^{-1}
$$

Comment: I is identity matrix, right? I will test it

Comment: I have try your solution but I have some problems. I have try to use a very simple example. These are the value a(1,2,0), u1(1,0,0), u2(0,1,0), and Point(3,4,0) on UCSA. So u3(0,0,1) and result should be Point'(4,6,0) but I get (0,-2,0)

Comment: The reason is the $u_i$. I assumed they were in world coordinates and will turn into the canonical basis by the transformation. Try again without the left matrix or set $A=id$.

Comment: The ui versors must be considered because define UCSA. If I only remove A matrix I ignore also ui versors. ui are versors define orientation of UCSA, OA define the origin of UCSA.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, coordinate systems are related by a change of origin and isotropic rescaling (and/or change of unit),

$$\begin{cases}x'=sx+p,\\y'=sy+q\end{cases}$$

or a similarity (if there is a rotation in between)

$$\begin{cases}x'=ux+vy+p,\\y'=vx-uy+q.\end{cases}$$

You can determine the coefficients by taking enough pairs of corresponding points, giving their coordinates in both frames and solving the equations for the unknown coefficients.

When geographic coordinates on a large scale are involved, the transformations are much more complex.

Similar equations hold for 3D. The rotation is expressed by a $3\times3$ orthogonal matrix.